# Que no aparezcan los que están en ceros en mi consulta de BD PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una pregunta, tengo una consulta de mysql con php el cual mando a llamar a todos los doctores
y luego hago otra consulta el cual checo las ganancias de cada medico e imprimo la suma total de todos pero la mayoria me aparecen en ceros por que no han generado nada. Todo esto lo hago en php y mysql.

Lo que quiero al momento de mostrarlo en mi reporte pdf quisiera que solo me muestre los que han generado dinero y los que no pues que no aparezcan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from medicos order by nombre_medico");

//Tiempo
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Mexico_City');
$mes_actual = date('m');

switch($mes_actual) {
    case '01':
        $m = "Enero";
    break;
    case '02':
        $m = "Febrero";
    break;
    case '03':
        $m = "Marzo";
    break;
    case '04':
        $m = "Abril";
    break;
    case '05':
        $m = "Mayo";
    break;
    case '06':
        $m = "Junio";
    break;
    case '07':
        $m = "Julio";
    break;
    case '08':
        $m = "Agosto";
    break;
    case '09':
        $m = "Septiembre";
    break;
    case '10':
        $m = "Octubre";
    break;
    case '11':
        $m = "Noviembre";
    break;
    case '12':
        $m = "Diciembre";
    break;
}
        
$cadena='
    <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 11pt;" border="1" CELLPADDING=5 CELLSPACING=0 bordercolor="#000000">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="width:85%; color:#17202a; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; padding: 4px 4px 4px;" align="center">Comisión de los médicos del mes de '.$m.' </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#2c3e50">
           <td style="color:white;font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;padding: 4px 4px 4px;">NÚM.</td>
           <td style="color:white;font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;padding: 4px 4px 4px;">ID</td>
           <td style="color:white;font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;padding: 4px 4px 4px;">MÉDICO</td>
           <td style="color:white;font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;padding: 4px 4px 4px;">COMISIÓN</td>
        </tr>
';
    $num=1;
    while ($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
        $id_medico = $rw['id_medico'];
$cadena.='
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><b>'.$num.'</b></td>
            <td>'.$rw['id_medico'].'</td>
            <td>'.$rw['nombre_medico'].'</td>
';      
        $sq = mysqli_query($con,"select sum(total_venta) as total from facturas where id_medico = '$id_medico' and CAST(fecha_factura AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 month) AND curdate()");
        
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sq)) {
            $com = $row["total"];
            $comision = ($com * 15) / 100;
                
            $cadena.='<td><b>$'.number_format($comision,2).'</b></td></tr>';
        }
        $num++;
    }   
$cadena.='
    </table>
';
```

Otra pregunta si habrá manera de hacerlo todo en una sola consulta y no en dos como lo hago yo o a fuerzas tiene que ser así como lo tengo?.

Otra pregunta como le haga si el cliente quiere verlo todo ó solo los que generan comisión y los que no generan nada, todo eso escogiéndolo desde un formulario?.

mis tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon la estructura de tus tablas para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: @Japv hola ya agregue las tablas y perdon la demora es que ando trabajando.

Comment: Te puedes ahorrar el montón de `switch - case` con una sola línea: `$m = ['Enero', 'Febrero', ..., 'Diciembre'][$mes_actual - 1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar sólo una **sentencia SQL con subconsultas** se haría de esta forma.

Primero defino una variable donde **guardo la subconsulta** que formará parte de las columnas **del resultado de medicos**.

```
$subconsulta = "SELECT sum(B.total_venta) from facturas AS B where B.id_medico = A.id_medico and CAST(B.fecha_factura AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 month) AND curdate()";
```

Luego en tu variable **$sql** agrego la subconsulta como nueva columna resultante y le pongo el **alias total**

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select A.*, ($subconsulta) AS total from medicos AS A order by A.nombre_medico");
```

Fíjate que le estoy colocando **ALIAS a las tablas**

```
// A es la tabla medicos
// B es la tabla facturas
```

Para recorrer la tabla resultante se hace así.

```
while ($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id_medico = $rw['id_medico'];
    $nombre_medico = $rw['nombre_medico'];

    $com = $row["total"];
    $comision = ($com * 15) / 100;
}
```

Y para filtrar sólo a los que han generado dinero. Se modificaría la variable **$sql** así.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select A.*, ($subconsulta) AS total from medicos AS A WHERE ($subconsulta) > 0 order by A.nombre_medico");
```

Answer (score 1):

No tengo del todo claro, como tienes tu base de datos, pero me supongo que son dos tablas una con solo los médicos y otra las facturas que van entrando por cada uno.

Al así:

medicos:

| id | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Nombre de médico |

facturas:

| id | id médico | factura |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 15 |

Y su correspondientes fechas, no las ponga para reducir el texto a escribir... xD

Asi que sí, se puede hacer en una única consulta, sería algo así:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.nombre, 
       SUM(b.total_venta) 
FROM medicos a 
INNER JOIN facturas b ON a.id = b.medico_id 
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Luego solo tendrías que añadir tus "filtros" correspondientes `WHERE b.total_venta > 0` y tu filtro de fechas.

Comment: ¿por qué en la preview sí me salió la tabla hecha, pero luego al publicar la respuesta sale así? :c

Comment: Pero no te hace falta por nombre, no? Ya se agrupa por el ID xD. Ya eso según como quieras

Comment: @BetaM  perdon ando trabajando pero ya puse la imagen de mis dos tablas.

Comment: @S.Wasta perdon ando trabajando pero ya puse la imagen de mis dos tablas.

Comment: En la tabla de factura utilizo total_venta y id_medico que esta ligado a la tabla de medicos.

Answer (score 1):

```
select g2.numFactura, t.idMedico, m2.nombreMedico, t.comision
(
select m.idMedico, sum(g.totalVenta) as comision
from medicos m
inner join ganancias g on m.idMedico = g.idMedico
group by m.idMedico
having sum(g.totalVenta > 0)
) t inner join medicos m2 
  on t.idMedico = m2.idMedico
  inner join ganancias g2
  on t.idMedico = g2.idMedico
```

Primero analicemos la **consulta interna**, en esta consulta se selecciona el **idMedico** y su **comisión**, para ello se hace un **group by** por el **campo idMedico**, y en el **select** se aplica la **función de agregación sum**, de esta forma obtenemos la comisión por cada médico, y utilizamos la **cláusula having** para obtener solamente los médicos cuya comisión sea mayor que **0**.

Ahora bien el uso del **group by** implica cumplir con ciertas reglas, es decir **el campo que no aparece en el group by debe aparecer en el select con una función de agregación**, de no cumplirse esta regla la consulta o bien dará error o devolverá datos no confiables, por eso en esta consulta no se selecciona el **campo numFactura** ni **nombreMedico**, solo se seleccionan el **idMedico** y la **comisión**. Para obtener los campos que faltan juntamos a través de la **cláusula inner join** los resultados devueltos por esta consulta con las **tablas médicos** y **ganancias**, y entonces hacemos un **select** más global seleccionando todos los campos que queremos.